# phantomjs stuck fetching SVG with base64 encoded pattern

Tags: svg, phantomjs

I am using https://github.com/vidalab/banquo-server to create an png from a svg which uses phantomjs.

I dont know if there is a problem with phantomjs or my svg which is why im posting here and not on github (quicker response too).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="creator-svg" width="488" height="350">
  <desc>Created with Snap</desc>
  <defs>
    <pattern x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" id="patternSibdh4mpauu" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
      <image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIxNSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxNSI+CjxyZWN0IHdpZHRoPSI1MCIgaGVpZ2h0PSI1MCIgZmlsbD0iIzI4MjgyOCI+PC9yZWN0Pgo8Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSIzIiBjeT0iNC4zIiByPSIxLjgiIGZpbGw9IiMzOTM5MzkiPjwvY2lyY2xlPgo8Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSIzIiBjeT0iMyIgcj0iMS44IiBmaWxsPSJibGFjayI+PC9jaXJjbGU+CjxjaXJjbGUgY3g9IjEwLjUiIGN5PSIxMi41IiByPSIxLjgiIGZpbGw9IiMzOTM5MzkiPjwvY2lyY2xlPgo8Y2lyY2xlIGN4PSIxMC41IiBjeT0iMTEuMyIgcj0iMS44IiBmaWxsPSJibGFjayI+PC9jaXJjbGU+Cjwvc3ZnPg==" preserveAspectRatio="none" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20"/>
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <g>
    <circle cx="244" cy="178" r="140" fill="url('#patternSibdh4mpauu')" stroke="#cdcdcd" style="stroke-width: 1px;"/>
    <circle cx="244" cy="178" r="120" fill="url('#patternSibdh4mpauu')" stroke="#cdcdcd" style="stroke-width: 1px;"/>
  </g>
  <image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://enterprise.app/badge-builder/resize/bet.png" preserveAspectRatio="none" x="140" y="140" width="300" height="298" transform="matrix(0.3733,-0.1067,0.1067,0.3733,125.9067,129.04)" class="" style="touch-action: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -webkit-user-drag: none; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); opacity: 0.6;"/>
</svg>
```

is my svg code. works in all browsers, no errors.

after banquo server failing I went to the phantomjs docs and picked up the rasterize.js script and tested from terminal, their example svg works, mine doesn't. So i started stripping bits out and it is infact the base64encoded patterns that are causing the problem.

Does anyone know if the svg format is incorrect or phantomjs has problems with the base64encoded format?

regards

*EDIT:*

removed the base64encoded pattern and changed to file path, still not working. Delete the contents of the file and it works...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="15" height="15">
    <rect width="50" height="50" fill="#282828"/>
    <circle cx="3" cy="4.3" r="1.8" fill="#393939"/>
    <circle cx="3" cy="3" r="1.8" fill="black"/>
    <circle cx="10.5" cy="12.5" r="1.8" fill="#393939" />
    <circle cx="10.5" cy="11.3" r="1.8" fill="black"/>
</svg>
```

is the file contents for the pattern

*EDIT 2:*

started removing bits of the pattern svg and will run if `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"` is removed but the image does not display...

Comment: Looks fine, except I failed to find the unusual, but perfectly valid definition of the xlink namespace.

Comment: removed the encoded link to an image and worked... must be an issue with phantomjs